# Is it possible to restrict an application distribution on Amazon appstore based on the country?

Tags: android, app-store, restriction, country, amazon-appstore

I want to publish an Android application on the Amazon Appstore, but I need to restrict availability and distribution of this application to Canada only.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know; why would you want to?

Comment: The application we're developing would address specific market needs in Canada. We plan to release the same application later in the US market when we'll be ready to address US market needs.

Comment: Btw, I just googled your question and first hit is Amazon FAQ where it is a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just login to your console   :[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the FAQ?

https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html

**Q: What should I do if I don’t want my app to be available in a particular country?**

To change the country availability, sign in to the Amazon Mobile App Distribution Portal and go to the My Apps tab. Once there, select the app you wish to edit for country availability, and click on the Availability and Pricing tab. On this tab, uncheck the box next to the country in which you do not want your app to be sold. The default will be to make your app available in all countries in which Amazon offers apps.